# Sort numpy string array using positional data

Tags: python, sorting, numpy

I have a numpy array of strings

```
names = array([
    'p00x00', 'p01x00', 'p02x00', 'p03x00', 'p04x00', 'p05x00',
    'p00x01', 'p01x01', 'p02x01', 'p03x01', 'p04x01', 'p05x01',
    'p00x02', 'p01x02', 'p02x02', 'p03x02', 'p04x02', 'p05x02',
    'p00x03', 'p01x03', 'p02x03', 'p03x03', 'p04x03', 'p05x03',
    'p00x04', 'p01x04', 'p02x04', 'p03x04', 'p04x04', 'p05x04',
    'p00x05', 'p01x05', 'p02x05', 'p03x05', 'p04x05', 'p05x05'])
```

And corresponding position data

```
X = array([2.102235, 2.094113, 2.086038, 2.077963, 2.069849, 2.061699])
Y = array([-7.788431, -7.780364, -7.772306, -7.764247, -7.756188, -7.748114])
```

How can I sort `names` using `X` and `Y` such that I get out a sorted grid of names with shape (6, 6)? Note that there are essentially 6 unique `X` and `Y` positions -- I'm not just arbitrarily choosing 6x6.

```
names = array([
    ['p00x00', 'p01x00', 'p02x00', 'p03x00', 'p04x00', 'p05x00'],
    ['p00x01', 'p01x01', 'p02x01', 'p03x01', 'p04x01', 'p05x01'],
    ['p00x02', 'p01x02', 'p02x02', 'p03x02', 'p04x02', 'p05x02'],
    ['p00x03', 'p01x03', 'p02x03', 'p03x03', 'p04x03', 'p05x03'],
    ['p00x04', 'p01x04', 'p02x04', 'p03x04', 'p04x04', 'p05x04'],
    ['p00x05', 'p01x05', 'p02x05', 'p03x05', 'p04x05', 'p05x05']])
```

I realize in this case that I could simply reshape the array, but in general the data will not work out this neatly.

Comment: To me it looks like there are 36 different x values and 36 different y values. I'm afraid that this question is not quite clear enough to be answered.

Comment: Nevertheless, I think `np.argsort` might be your solution here.

Comment: Perhaps `names = names.reshape(6,6)`?

Comment: @ThomasKühn agreed that strictly speaking there are 36 unique values in x and y, but 6 values differ by ~0.01 while the others differ by ~0.0001.

Comment: @unutbu that would work fine here, but that's why I added that last note about in general the data will not work out pre-sorted as it is here.

Comment: @lanery So what do you now want to do exactly? Sort `names` corresponding to the order of `x`, but for `x` there should be a tolerance? I still don't get it. I would understand if `x` and `y` would be 6-element arrays, or 6x6 `meshgrids`.

Comment: @ThomasKühn let's say then that x and y are 6-element arrays. I'll edit the question.

Comment: @lanery I just realised that my output is not exactly what you expected -- I'm not quite sure if that is because I understood your question wrong or the desired output you show does not match the order in the `X` and `Y` you show. If you still have some questions, let me know.

Comment: @ThomasKühn I noticed that and maybe should have clarified, but I just reversed (`[::-1]`) `x_ordered` and took the transpose of the output to get the correct order. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `numpy.argsort` to get the indexes of the elements of an array after it's sorted. These indices you can then use to sort your `names` array.

```
import numpy as np

names = np.array([
    'p00x00', 'p01x00', 'p02x00', 'p03x00', 'p04x00', 'p05x00',
    'p00x01', 'p01x01', 'p02x01', 'p03x01', 'p04x01', 'p05x01',
    'p00x02', 'p01x02', 'p02x02', 'p03x02', 'p04x02', 'p05x02',
    'p00x03', 'p01x03', 'p02x03', 'p03x03', 'p04x03', 'p05x03',
    'p00x04', 'p01x04', 'p02x04', 'p03x04', 'p04x04', 'p05x04',
    'p00x05', 'p01x05', 'p02x05', 'p03x05', 'p04x05', 'p05x05'])

X = np.array([2.102235, 2.094113, 2.086038, 2.077963, 2.069849, 2.061699])
Y = np.array([-7.788431, -7.780364, -7.772306, -7.764247, -7.756188, -7.748114])

x_order = np.argsort(X)
y_order = np.argsort(Y)

names_ordered = names.reshape(6,6)[np.meshgrid(x_order,y_order)]

print(names_ordered)
```

gives the following output:

```
[['p00x05' 'p00x04' 'p00x03' 'p00x02' 'p00x01' 'p00x00']
 ['p01x05' 'p01x04' 'p01x03' 'p01x02' 'p01x01' 'p01x00']
 ['p02x05' 'p02x04' 'p02x03' 'p02x02' 'p02x01' 'p02x00']
 ['p03x05' 'p03x04' 'p03x03' 'p03x02' 'p03x01' 'p03x00']
 ['p04x05' 'p04x04' 'p04x03' 'p04x02' 'p04x01' 'p04x00']
 ['p05x05' 'p05x04' 'p05x03' 'p05x02' 'p05x01' 'p05x00']]
```